# How can i import function or class from one folder to another folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, package, python-import

I am using python 3.6 . I have following folder structure:

```
main_directory
-- sub_directory_one
   -- config.py
-- sub_directory_two
   -- test.py
```

i want to import function or class from config.py to test.py .
i Have tried

```
from sub_directory_one.config import class_name
from main_directory.sub_directory_one.config import class_name
```

But nothing is working.
Few have suggested about adding project to system path.But i am currently working on mac and what will happen if deploy this to ubuntu server.

Thanks

Comment: Try: 
    from .sub_directory_one.config import class_name

Comment: You probably want to look at instructions on how to create modules and packages, because instead of relying on a specific directory structure and referencing files like this, you should probably just package things properly and import from those - that would work without issue across OSes (a justifiable concern). If you feel there is no need to package them up, you might ask yourself if there really is a reason to stick the files in separate folders in the first place?

Comment: @AdrianDaniszewski this gives ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.sub_directory_one'; '__main__' is not a package

Comment: @Grismar .  Its Big project the directory sample i just shared is just for reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your sub directories are (supposed to be) Python **packages**, add an empty `__init__.py` file in these directories. If you then run your main application from the main directory, you should be able to use:

```
from sub_directory_one.config import class_name
```

Alternatively, if `config.py` and `test.py` are Python **modules** that are just separated in different directories for whatever practical reasons, you should add the sub directories to your Python search path. This can be done by setting the environment variable PYTHONPATH before starting your main application, or by extending the Python variable `sys.path` in your main script before importing these modules. In that case you should use:

```
from config import class_name
```

For more information about Python modules and packages, see the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html).